Power BI/ Power Automate Possible Solution
I built a Power BI report that displays inventory quantities for different sales reps and calculates DII (how fast those products are turning) using their quantities sold. My company wants to add the ability for the sales reps to adjust the inventory quantities to see the effect that would have on their DII number for that product and overall. I know Power BI is not designed to take in user input so I will have to use a solution like Power Apps to do this. I've tried a few methods and researched many more and they all seem to have some type of limitation for my use case. The attached image shows the solution I'm trying to create. The highlighted column is the only that that needs to be adjusted by the user, all other columns will be imported from Power BI. Here are my main requirements:
-Data must refresh daily to capture current inventory levels
-User inputs must be reflected in dashboard instantly so new DII can be calculated
I am currently exploring using a combo of Power BI, Power Automate, SharePoint and Power Apps to achieve this result.
Here are the steps I was envisioning:

Export table of current values from Power BI into SharePoint excel file using Power Automate.
Create PowerApp visual/app that allows users to adjust the inventory column in that table
Refresh dashboard to reflect user input and calculate new DII value.

The issues I'm running into are:

SharePoint excel table cannot have a direct query connection.
PowerApps requires a key column which my table doesn't currently have.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
